# Play music file in a conference or play the file to a specific user in side the conference

Tags: asterisk

I want to play a music file inside a conference to only a particular member of the conference?
How to do this? Even I am not able to play a music file inside a conference, I tried with dialing local channels but did not help.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really posible, but if you to go waaaay off the beaten path, here are two (majorly hacky) solutions:

1. Put just that user in MeetmeA, put every one else in MeetmeB. Set your music to be the music on hold for MeetmeA. Originate a call from MeetmeA to MeetmeB, making sure that participant 'MeetmeA' (i.e. the meetme, not just the user inside the meetme) is MUTED.
2. Probably much easier - use chanspy and "whisper" the music to that specifc participant